# Не выполняется условие

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

По какой-то причине условие if не исполняется, соответственно и тег не меняется.
Названия сходятся, в другой части кода ошибок нет

```
    function replaceAd() {
    let ads = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (ad in ads) {
        if (ad.className == "Placeholder") {
            ad.innerHTML = "<p>123</p>";
        };
    };
};
```

[image: Список тэгов div]

Comment: что такое `ad`? Какое значение этой переменной? Оператор `in` - работает не так как ты думаешь

Comment: вместо ad стоит писать ads[ad], либо использовать цикл for of

Comment: @Олег cпасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

внутри цикла [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) в переменную заносится не элемент коллекции, а ключ.

В данном случае 0, 1, 2 и т.д. причем ключ является строкой, поэтому

```
ad.className
```

всегда будет `undefined`, так как такого свойства у строки нет.

Для решения нужно брать элемент по соответствующему индексу

```
const el = ads[ad];

if (el.className == "Placeholder") { ... }
```

Либо воспользоваться [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), внутри которого будет именно элемент, а не индекс.

Либо воспользоваться обычным [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
for(var index=0; index<ads.length; index ++){
    const ad = ads[index];
    if (ad.className == "Placeholder") { ... }
}
```